# iTunes Connect TestFlight, role for submitting apps

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

From what I can tell from this https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/ you need to have the role of "Agent" in iTunes Connect to submit apps even for testing purposes (using TestFlight). Is this correct?

Is it correct that there can only be one Agent assigned to an iTunes Connect account?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question, hope it's ok.

No, you do not need to be an agent to submit binaries ti iTunes Connect.

My issue was that my iTunes Connect account and my Apple Developer account were using different Apple Id's (email adresses). In that case XCode will not allow you to submit the binary, instead you need to use Application Loader.